# Как в TextView записать химическую формулу?

Tags: java, android, xml, textview

Как в `TextView` записать химическую формулу с верхними и нижними символами?

Как пример - как вывести такую формулу:
[image]

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Например, с помощью HTML тегов:

- Верхний индекс: `<sup>upper</sup>`;
- Нижний индекс: `<sub>lower</sub>`;

---

```
String s = "<sup>upper</sup><sub>lower</sub>";
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
    mTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml(s, Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY));
} else {
    mTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml(s));
}
```

В качестве альтернативного варианта можно использовать `SpannableStringBuilder`:

```
SpannableStringBuilder ssb = new SpannableStringBuilder("Cu+6");
ssb.setSpan(new SuperscriptSpan(), 2, 3, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
ssb.setSpan(new RelativeSizeSpan(0.75f), 2, 3, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
ssb.setSpan(new SubscriptSpan(), 3, 4, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
ssb.setSpan(new RelativeSizeSpan(0.75f), 3, 4, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
mTextView.setText(ssb);
```

**UPD:** В строке, которая хранится в ресурсах, необходимо заменить `<` на `&lt;` (*less-than sign*), а `>` на `&gt;` (*greater-than sign*):

```
<string name="str">&lt;sup&gt;upper&lt;/sup&gt;&lt;sub>lower&lt;/sub&gt;</string>
```

Comment: а в файле strings.xml как сделать запись, что использовать, как ресурс?

Comment: @МаксимФомичёв, Обновил ответ.

Comment: спасибо огромное!

Answer (score 0):

**u** + **v** = (u<sub>1</sub>+v<sub>1</sub>, u<sub>2</sub>+v<sub>2</sub>, ..., u<sub>n</sub>+v<sub>n</sub>)

c**u** = (cu<sub>1</sub>, cu<sub>2</sub>, ..., cu<sub>n</sub>), где c - скаляр

Скалярное произведение **u**•**v** = u<sub>1</sub>v<sub>1</sub> + u<sub>2</sub>v<sub>2</sub> + ... + u<sub>n</sub>v<sub>n</sub>

Норма вектора ||**u**|| = √(u<sub>1</sub><sup>2</sup>+u<sub>2</sub><sup>2</sup>+...+u<sub>n</sub><sup>2</sup>)

Comment: Информация классная, но это не похоже на ответ на данный вопрос ;)